# How to include paypal fee

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Currently I am using paypal for online payments. 
There are some fees that paypal charges per transaction. Amount to charge depends on several factors such as currency(country) and card type.
And this causes problems as these fees are subtracted from my "wanted" price.
So I am wondering whether there are some special ways to include this fees to base-price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually against the PayPal terms of service to add the fee on top of the price. If you get caught doing this, your account can be suspended.

From PayPal [Terms of service](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=ua/UserAgreement_full&locale.x=en_US):

> 4.6 No Surcharges. You agree that you will not impose a surcharge or any other fee for accepting PayPal as a payment method. You may charge
>   a handling fee in connection with the sale of goods or services, as
>   long as the handling fee does not operate as a surcharge and is not
>   higher than the handling fee you charge for non-PayPal transactions.

The only way to (legally) do this is to use the adaptive payments API, which allows you to select what party pays the fee (sender or receiver).  However, you have to make a business case for it before they approve it.

More info here: [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments)
(Look for feesPayer parameter in the documentation.